# Scala lists,map and flatMap

Tags: scala, operators

I am looking now at he example from M.Odersky's book

```
List.range(1, 5) flatMap (
i => List.range(1, i) map (j => (i, j))
)
```

Ok,first we create list of `1,2,3,4` then what happens next?What is

```
i => List.range(1, i)
```

doing?Creating

```
(1,1)
(1,2)
(1,3)
(1,4)
```

Yes or no?

If I try to evade flatMap

```
scala> List.range(1,5) (i => List.range(1,i) map (j => (i, j)))
<console>:11: error: missing parameter type
       List.range(1,5) (i => List.range(1,i) map (j => (i, j)))
```

Why?

Comment: It's `(i => ((List.range(1, i)) map (j => (i, j))))`. So **no**, and the expression `i => List.range(1, i)` is not a part of the full code

Comment: This question has nothing to do with "operator precedence". Why did you choose that for the title?

Comment: @jwvh I have chenged my title,I want to understand code step bu step.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to develop an understanding of some code is to plug it into the REPL, break it down into its constituent parts, and put it back together again.

```
List.range(1,5)  // List(1, 2, 3, 4), pretty simple

List.range(1,5).map(i => i)  // no change (map is simpler than flatMap)

List.range(1,5).map(i => List.range(1, i))
res2: List[List[Int]] = List(List(), List(1), List(1, 2), List(1, 2, 3))
```

OK, so each element of the original List has become a new sub-List. Let's see what `flatMap` does.

```
List.range(1,5).flatMap(i => List.range(1, i))
res3: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3)
```

So if `map` produces Lists within a List, then `flatMap` "flattens" it all out to a single List.

Continuing on with this trial-and-error, test-and-retest, method you should be able to demonstrate for yourself what the rest of the code is doing (that's where the resulting tuples are created).